# mongoose findone return undefine

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a bot. It can input some text and return some word.

I would like to use MongoDB. Because Heroku can't store data.

So I add function.js that use mongoose.

```
 console.log('data.functionswitch = ' + data.functionswitch);
```

console log is work fine. It can reply what i want.

```
 return data.functionswitch;
```

but  return data.functionswitch  only return undefined when i call it in input.js/.

I have try async/await.

But it only stops working.

How can I improve it and make it work? Thank you.

-

-

2018/03/15 updated

function.js

```
function switchfind(id, name, callback) {
mongodb.functionSwitch.findOne({
    groupid: id, functionname: name
}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(null);
        return;
    }

    else if (!data) {
        console.log("No record found")
        callback(null);
        return;
    }
    console.log('date = ' + data);
    console.log('data.functionswitch = ' + data.functionswitch);
     callback(data.functionswitch);
    return;
})
};
```

input.js

```
function parseInput(rplyToken, inputStr) {
//console.log('InputStr: ' + inputStr);
_isNaN = function (obj) {
    return isNaN(parseInt(obj));
}

let msgSplitor = (/\S+/ig);
let mainMsg = inputStr.match(msgSplitor); 
let trigger = mainMsg[0].toString().toLowerCase(); 

exports.mongoose.switchfind(mainMsg[1], mainMsg[2], function (functionswitch) {
    console.log('functionswitch = ' + functionswitch)

    if (functionswitch === null) {
        console.log('HERE === NULL ')
    }
    if (functionswitch == 0) {
        console.log('HERE != 0')
        return;
    }
    else if (functionswitch != 0 ) {
        console.log('HERE != 0')


        if (inputStr.match(/\w/) != null && inputStr.toLowerCase().match(/\d+d+\d/) != null) return exports.rollbase.nomalDiceRoller(inputStr, mainMsg[0], mainMsg[1], mainMsg[2]);

    }

})

}
```

update

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let uristring = process.env.mongoURL ||
'mongodb://XXXXXXX';
mongoose.connect(uristring);

mongoose.connect(uristring, function (err, res) {
if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
} else {
    console.log('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
    // console.log('allswitch: ' + allswitch);
}
});

var functionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
groupid: String,
functionname: String,
functionswitch: String
});

// Compiles the schema into a model, opening (or creating, if
// nonexistent) the 'PowerUsers' collection in the MongoDB database
var functionSwitch = mongoose.model('functionSwitchs', functionSchema);
```

Comment: try  `else if (!data)` instead of else `if (data == null)`

Comment: Tried and same result. 

I have try  console.log("return = "+exports.mongoose.switchfind(mainMsg[1], mainMsg[2]));
but also show  undefined .

Comment: What is the schema ? `functionSwitch`

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT  UPDATED

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are using `findOne` as it was synchronous. You cannot simply return the data, you have to use a `callback`.

[Here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) is a tutorial about callbacks.

---

Example of what it should look like :

```
// The find function
function switchfind(id, name, callback) {
  mongodb.functionSwitch.findOne({
    groupid: id,
    functionname: name
  }, function (err, data) {
    // Handle error
    if (err) {
      callback(null);

      return;
    }

    // Handle empty data
    if (data == null) {
      callback(null);

      return;
    }

    // Handle with data
    callback(data.functionswitch);
  })
};
```

---

```
// How to call it
funcX() {
  switchfind(id, name, function (functionswitch) {
    if (functionswitch === null) {
      // Handle the error
    }

    // Handle the data
  });
}
```